# Mixpanel push notification text not getting enlarged on Android devices

Tags: android, push-notification, mixpanel

Account details on Mixpanel:

```
maaz.shaikh@bwellthy.com
Notification text: Hey {{USER_NICK_NAME}}, you can check your HbA1c test result by clicking on it, then click GET STARTED to start your journey with us.

Notification custom packet: { "mp_icnm_l": "app_logo", "mp_icnm_w": "notification_logo", "mp_color": "#FF7531", "sound": "yes", "vibrate": "yes"}
```

[The notification pops up on android device like this, but does not enlarge on dragging it downwards](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S9qrX.jpg)

I am using the latest release of Mixpanel(v5.2.1) in the Android code.
Mixpanel is using BigStyle Text notifications in their library, so ideally the single line notification on dragging should enlarge on dragging it.

Can you tell me the possible reason for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use BigTextStyle for setting big text in notification.**

```
Notification notification = new Notification.Builder(mContext)
     .setContentTitle("New mail from " + sender.toString())
     .setContentText(subject)
     .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.new_mail)
     .setLargeIcon(aBitmap)
     .setStyle(new Notification.BigTextStyle()
         .bigText(aVeryLongString))
     .build();
```